# Django, retrieving user profile using library User without call models

Tags: python, django, profile

I try to show user profile base on PK. So, I created a menu where the name is "Profile". After a user clicks the menu, the user can see the profile.

I tried this:

```
def view_profile(request, pk):
    profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'girl/base.html', {'profile':profile})
```

And also this:

```
def view_profile(request, pk):
    profile = User.objects.filter(User, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'profile':profile})
```

---

In base.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href='{% url "profile" pk=profile.pk%}' class="prof"><span class="pro">Profile</span></a>
{% endif %}
```

And in the template, profile.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2><a href="{% url 'profile' pk=profile.pk %}">{{ profile.username }}</a></h2>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<pk>\d+)/profile/$', views.view_profile, name='profile')
```

The profile never showed, I got the following error:

```
Reverse for 'profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cat/(?P<pk>\\d+)/profile/$']
```

Comment: The error is same.

Comment: replace `profile = User.objects.filter(User, pk=pk)` to `User.objects.filter(pk=pk)`

Comment: The error still same Mr. Victor

Comment: @Scarlettstone Check source code of your profile.html  in browser and make sure you have pk there, and url is in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really hard to understand, so I'm making a guess.

You have a thing called "profile" only in the context of your profile view itself. But your base template is used for *all* views, and all other views *don't* have that variable available; so it can't use the value to create a profile link.

However I don't know why you think you need this variable. The thing you want is not the profile at all, but the current user; that is always available in templates, via the variable called unsurprisingly `user` - as you know, because you're already using it to check the authentication status. You should use that in your base template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href='{% url "profile" pk=user.pk%}' class="prof"><span class="pro">Profile</span></a>
{% endif %}
```

Note also that your second version of the Profile view itself is just wrong.

Comment: I mean, i want to show the profile of user. i was try like you do, but the error still same.